# how to get tweet count for the last ten minutes from the sample table

Tags: mysql, sql, hive

I am trying to get tweet counts for the last ten minutes of a game
assuming I have a sample table as below
id 2   starttime   2005-11-10 16:30:00  endtime  2005-11-10 18:22:

then I have a tweettable  as below

tweet id 28215441122544   created 2005-11-10 18:13:43
  .
tweet id 25889966555552   created 2005-11-10 18:14:15

how would I write this as a query to count the tweet that occurred within the last ten mins of the sample table. I have tried all sorts, am new to SQL and hive, any help is appreciated.

Comment: add your code you are working on

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE created >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
```

EDIT: if you need enddate from your other table, you will need to use something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE created >= (select endtime from othertable where id=2) - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
```

In the question, we are not provided the info that how to connect the tables by using Id column (that's why Id=3 hardcoded here), but the OP knows I believe.

Comment: "how would I write this as a query to count the tweet that occurred within the last ten mins of the sample table" this query doesn't do that.

Comment: hi so the id in the other table is just one at of 50 so i am trying to get the count for each id for las 10 minutes and order them by the highest tweetcount

Comment: @okechukwuanya are you saying there are two tables to read from? If so please update your question.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the number of tweets (rows) in the last ten minutes

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM sampleTable
WHERE create > date_sub(sysdate(), interval 10 minute)
```